# Angular JS: Service Response not Saving to Variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I'm trying to work out why the response of this service isn't saving to  `$scope.counter`. I've added a function to my service `fetchCustomers(p)` which takes some parameters and returns a number, which I'd like to save to `$scope.counter`.

**service**

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('MyService', MyService)

function MyService($http) {
  var url = 'URL'';

  return {
    fetchTotal: function(p) {
      return $http.get(url, { params: p })
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.data.meta.total;
        }, function(error) {
          console.log("error occured");
        })
    }
  }
}
```

**controller**

```
$scope.counter = MyService.fetchTotal(params).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  return response;
});
```

For some reason though, this isn't working. It's console logging the value, but not saving it to `$scope.counter`. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably just a typo but you have an extra quote around `'URL''`

Comment: you're assigning `$scope.counter` to the returned promise, not the response. Your callback should have the assignment `$scope.counter = response`

Comment: Yeah sorry, that's a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're setting `$scope.counter` to a promise, not the response.

```
MyService.fetchTotal(params).then(function(response) {
  // Anything dealing with data from the server
  // must be put inside this callback
  $scope.counter = response;
  console.log($scope.counter); // Data from server
});

// Don't do this
console.log($scope.counter); // Undefined
```

Comment: But when I now do a `$scope.counter`, it comes back as undefined: `MyService.fetchTotalCustomers(params).then(function(response) {
  $scope.counter = response;
});

console.log($scope.counter);`

Comment: `console.log(response.data.meta.total)` in your service, see if thats undefined.

Comment: That logs out the number. This is why it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Put this inside the promise callback. `.then(function(response) { $scope.counter = response; console.log($scope.counter); });` Notice the `console.log()` is now inside the promise callback.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand??

Comment: Hey I made edit to previous comment. Also, the key thing to know here is that you were running `console.log()` immediately after `$http` request was made, meaning it was being executed before you received a response from the server.

Comment: But how do I expose $scope.counter outside that promise callback? That's the thing I'm having trouble with. I'm trying to use {{ counter }} in my view.

Comment: As soon as you set `$scope.counter` in the promise callback, it's available for use in the view. It should be working at this point. Have you tested it? If not, update your question with your HTML markup

Comment: I'm being stupid. It's been a long day. I was rendering {{ counter.value }} in my markup when all I needed was {{ counter }}. Thank you for all your help.